# How do I create a Factory for a generic type?

Tags: java, generics, factory

I need to create a single Factory object that can return an object with a specific parameterized type. That is, I need to specify the parameterized type of the object in the factory method. An example is the best way I can think to explain it, so consider the following class definitions.

```
interface Color {
    int getColor();
}

abstract class Animal<T extends Color> {
    T color;
    Animal(T col) { color = col; }
    public T getColor() { return color; }
}

class Dog<T extends Color> extends Animal<T> {
    public Dog(T col) {
        super(col);
    }
    public void woof() {
        System.out.println("Woof");
    }
}

class Cat<T extends Color> extends Animal<T> {
    public Cat(T col) {
        super(col);
    }
    public void meow() {
        System.out.println("Meow");
    }
}

class Blue implements Color {
    public int getColor() {
        return 1;
    }
    public void iAmBlue() {
        System.out.println("I am blue.");
    }
}

class Red implements Color {
    public int getColor() {
        return 2;
    }
}

// Expecting a base Factory interface that's something like this?
public interface Factory<K extends Animal<? extends Color>> {
    public <T extends Color> K create(T color);
}

public class CatFactory implements Factory<Cat<? extends Color>> {
    @Override // I want this to return Cat<T>, not Cat<?>
    public <T extends Color> Cat<? extends Color> create(T color) {
        return new Cat<T>(color);
    }
}
```

I basically need to create a single Factory object that can create any Dog (`Dog<Red>` or `Dog<Blue>`), and a separate object that can create any Cat (`Cat<Red>` or `Cat<Blue>`). When constructing object, I need it to be able to return `Dog<Red>` or `Dog<Blue>`, not `Animal<?>` or `Dog<?>`. Therefore, something like this should be valid (no type-casting required):

```
dogFactory.create(new Red()).woof();
dogFactory.create(new Blue()).getColor().iAmBlue();
```

Comment: So you have two separate type parameters `K` (from the class) and `T` (from the method call), and you want the return type to be `K<T>`. I don't think you can do that, interesting problem though.

Comment: @immibis yeah, that's exactly what I want. I've been struggling with it for a bit. I guess what I want isn't possible. I wanted to avoid instantiating a factory for each `T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `dogFactory.create(new Blue()).getColor().iAmBlue()`, I would conclude that you need to hold somewhere in the factory the *type* of the `Color`. And since the `create()` method is currently the only one that holds it, you'd need it's type parameter extracted at class-level. Something like:

```
public interface Factory<T extends Color, K extends Animal<T>> {
    public K create();
}
```

This will require changing the factory implementation to:

```
public class CatFactory<T extends Color> implements Factory<T, Cat<T>> {

    private T color;

    public CatFactory(T color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public Cat<T> create() {
        return new Cat<T>(color);
    }

    public T getColor() {
        return color;
    }

}
```

Now, you'd be able to do what's desired in the sample, by instantiating the factory like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CatFactory<Blue> blueCatsFactory = new CatFactory<Blue>(new Blue());
    blueCatsFactory.create().meow();
    blueCatsFactory.create().getColor().iAmBlue();
}
```

Comment: This works fine, and it might be the only/best way to do it. The type parameter `T` may very quite a bit so I didn't want to instantiate a new factory for each `T` but I fear that it may be unavoidable.